# Проблемы с классом с++

Tags: c++

У меня задание создать класс компьютер, в нем у меня различные данные вроде видеокарты, памяти и процессора. Основное задание было сделать что-то вроде меню, в котором при нажатии кнопки 2 показываются все компьютеры, у которых жесткий диск больше 600 гб, при нажатии на кнопку 3 выводятся все компьютеры без двд привода. У меня это все вышло и работает, проблема с копкой 4. Она должна вывести все компьютеры, у которых указан процессор. Вот это и не выходит, потому как программа выводит только один из компьютеров, даже если у обоих указан.

```
//Print proc
void Presenter::getComputersByProcessor(string processor)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < objCount; i++)
        if (computers[i]->getprocessor()==processor)
            printComputerInfo(computers[i]);

}
```

Comment: что выводит `computers[i]->getprocessor()`  ?
    
getprocessor()// лучше назвать getProcessor()

Comment: Под отладчиком смотрели? Чему равна objCount в момент выполнения? Может вы ее в `printComputerInfo` меняете?

Comment: Или // if для начала - теперь выводит ВСЕ компьютеры или нет?
Кто такой computers - обычный массив или контейнер?

Comment: Computers контейнер. Выводит один какой-то компьютер,хотя у всех есть процессор. А еще вопрос.Как мне сделать так,чтобы процессор можно было и не указывать? А то у менч в задании вывести по нажатии кнопки 4 все компьютеры с процемсором.

Comment: 1. Если комп без процессора (!!!), то пусть getprocessor() возвращает пустую строку. Вот и выведите только те, для которых computers[i]->getprocessor()== "". 

2. Выводит только один компьютер потому что только у него единственного computers[i]->getprocessor()==processor, как и задано в условии. ЛИБО что-то с контейнером, ЛИБО что-то с objCount, как справедливо заметил @Donil.

3. А такой код выводит все процессоры?
        for(int i = 0; i < objCount; i++)
            printComputerInfo(computers[i]);

Comment: проще засунуть все ваши компьютеры в map или простой вектор и та мих искать.